# How do I get GitHub Copilot on VSCode to prompt for new login credentials?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github, github-copilot

I'm using VSCode on WSL2 (Ubuntu) and i have installed the Github Copilot plugin, but i am having an issue.

VSCode correctly asks me to login.
However it doesn't ask for a username/e-mail.
it somehow can find a username/e-mail address even though i've reset/deleted everything that i could find here.

Windows credential manager is irrelevant, its on wsl. Even so, It's "empty", there's nothing github in it.
I did run git config --global --unset credential.helper both on windows as well as linux
I did delete ~/.gitconfig both on windows as well as linux
git config --global --list shows an error message that it can't find .gitconfig, correctly so.
There isn't anything git in /etc
I have revoked all tokens/applications on github.com so there's no tokens there.
I have deleted the keychains.
Seahorse shows no keys in the keychain.

The question is where does vscode get it from (or the github authentication plugin for vscode) and how do i remove that so that it starts asking for the username/e-mail address.

---

So the solution to this conundrum is that it is using an authentication cookie that is stored by the web browser. So you can try to delete/purge/anything on git/github/vscode what you like, it will continue to persist, even through a re-installation as it's looking into the cookie jar of the web browser. The web browser doesn't even need to be opened.